# Software randomly crashes with SEHException when run from LAN

Tags: c#, .net, exception, network-programming, unmanaged

I am maintaining a software and this issue has been largely reported by users.

It is installed in a shared folder on the company LAN and users usually launch it on their own computer by using a shortcut. This way, it only needs to be installed once and can be updated quickly.

The software would randomly crash, following a click on the UI. It seems that the more time passes, the more likely this is to happen. I could finally winess the crash on my own computer whithin Visual Studio and it showed a System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException with an error code of -2147467259, saying that an external component has thrown an exception. It's worth noting that this bug never happens if the software is installed on the local computer.

I could find little information about how to investigate and fix this problem. From what I've understood, this kind of exception is thrown from unmanaged code. But that doesn't get me very far as it covers many exceptions (once again this is what I get, I could be wrong).

A colleague suggested that it could have something to do with the network, like the connection going down. Indeed, I found out the same bug would happen every time I purposefully deactivated connection to the LAN.

But now what? Obviously the software can't run properly when it is located on a remote machine and the connection to that machine is lost. But what can I do, given the deployement model my company chose? Also I don't understand how such issue is so frequent for all of our clients

What solutions can I try to fix this problem or work around it?

**Edit :**

This is one stacktrace I could gather :

> MyApp.Form_MessageOkCancel..ctor(String texte, List`1
>   listLogF, Boolean debugF, Double zoomF)
>   MyApp.Form1.fermerLapplicationSplit_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.MenuItemData.Execute()
>   System.Windows.Forms.Command.Invoke()
>   System.Windows.Forms.Command.DispatchID(Int32 id)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>   MyApp.SplitButton.WndProc(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>   MyApp.Program.Main()
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)     System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

And the Form_MessageOkCancel.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IM;
```

_

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form_MessageOkCancel : Form
    {
        public IM.ClassCF.Colors colors { get; set; }

        IM.ClassCF classCF = new IM.ClassCF();

        List<IM.ClassCF.Log> listLog = new List<IM.ClassCF.Log>();
        bool debug;
        double zoom = 1;

        public Form_MessageOkCancel(string texte, List<IM.ClassCF.Log> listLogF, bool debugF, double zoomF)
        {
            try
            {
                listLog = listLogF;
                debug = debugF;
                zoom = zoomF;
                if (debug) classCF.AddLog(listLog, "Form_MessageOkCancel", "Form_MessageOkCancel", "<< Start", "");

                InitializeComponent();
                Design();
                labelText.Text = texte;
                this.Height = panel.Top + panel.Height + 94;
                if (debug) classCF.AddLog(listLog, "Form_MessageOkCancel", "Form_MessageOkCancel", ">> End", "");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                if (debug) classCF.AddLog(listLog, "Form_MessageOkCancel", "Form_MessageOkCancel", "<> Error", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Design()
        {
            try
            {
                if (debug) classCF.AddLog(listLog, "Form_MessageOkCancel", "Design", "Start", "");
                colors = classCF.UploadColors(listLog, debug);
                this.BackColor = colors.fondM;
                panel.BackColor = colors.fondC;
                btnOk.BackColor = colors.btnFondC;
                btnOk.ForeColor = colors.btnEcritureF;
                btnCancel.BackColor = colors.btnFondC;
                btnCancel.ForeColor = colors.btnEcritureF;

                btnOk.Text = IM.WinFormStrings.Ok;
                btnCancel.Text = IM.WinFormStrings.Cancel;
                if (debug) classCF.AddLog(listLog, "Form_MessageOkCancel", "Design", "End", "");             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (debug) classCF.AddLog(listLog, "Form_MessageOkCancel", "Design", "", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your post with the type of the exception and its full stack trace.

Comment: This is an error starting with 0x8.  These errors are caused by an invalid pointer (address).  Probably there is a timeout occurring an a function is returning a null.  So you are not checking for nulls.  If it is a TCP connection you can increase the default timeouts for a connection which may help

Comment: When I searched this https://www.google.com/search?q=2147467259 I found that these types of error messages are thrown when there is no equivalent managed code error mapping.  It means that the code handling this missed this exception.  The only thing you can do is, in your managed code put in a try catch of the global Exception and then determine what you need to retry.  You cannot stop the error in code you can't own and change.

Comment: @mjwills I added the information you asked. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please update your post with the entire source code of `Form_MessageOkCancel`.

Comment: @mjwills Done. But there is not much to see there(beside ugly code), that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: @JohnPeters By catching the global exception, do you mean that I should put the try...catch in the Main()?

Comment: Could be at main or within just the method where exception is seen/not seen.  Point is, it must be handled.